# How to use Regex to replace multiple sequences with values in a list?

Tags: javascript, java, regex, string

I have a situation where I need some string manipulation using regular expressions and I have never worked on regex.

MY String is something like this 
" This is [[Make]] and the value of [[Make]] is [[[BMW]]] and Availability of this [[[BMW]]]  is very [High] in market. another value for the [[Make]] is [[[Audi]]] and availability of [[[Audi]]] is [Moderate]".

I have three list of type String.
list1 with 3 String elements which would be used to replace
the characters between [[ ]] only. So first [[Make]] would be replaced by first element in list1. second [[Make]] would be replaced by 2nd element in the list and so on.

Similar concept can be applied on list2 which is also a list with string elements.
 list 2 will replace all the elements between [[[ ]]] and that too sequence wise. so this list has 4 elements.

List3 is again a list of String with 2 elements which would replace content between [] only.

Now the problem I am facing is that Whatever regular expression I use to replace the content for [ ] with list3, it tries to replace the content between [[ ]] and [[[ ]]] also.

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Your attempt is missing (I mean, show some code) :-)

Comment: It is possible to write regular expressions to handle the brackets appropriately, but another option is just to replace the triple bracket placeholders first, then the doubles, then the singles...

Comment: @nnnnnn But that means that he has to parse the string thrice

Comment: @nnnnnn I dont want to replace the [[[ ]]] brackets. I want the content between them.

Comment: @KumarM - I assumed the OP's existing code (not shown) was already doing this as three separate operations. So just doing them in reverse would solve the problem.

Comment: Show some code buddy :-| I don't understand what you are trying to achieve based on your explainations...

Comment: Ngupta - Really? You want the brackets in the *output*? I wouldn't have guessed that from the way you worded your question. OK then. By the way, are you trying to do this with JavaScript or Java?

Comment: Why would you get the content of the brackets since your replacement is based on the index of the occurrence?

Comment: @nnnnnn  I will use that string to do some other processing in my application. that's why I need to change the content of brackets.

Comment: @wawawared its not that I can not show you the code but I do not have any code . 
I can give you three list of strings and one string. But as myself anything I think of , I see the flaw in the logic, hence no code. however my method takes one string parameter and 3 lists  and with each list I need to replace the content.

Comment: Yeah, you should have shown the lists, the original string and the desired string after the replacement. Anyway, you got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the idea

```
    String s = " [x] [[x]]".replaceAll("(?<!\\[)\\[(?!\\[).*?\\]", "[1]");
```

it replaces only [x] and leaves [[x]] as is. It uses negative look behind `(?<!\\[)` to skip double brackets

Comment: Thanks a lot man. This is what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution:

```js
var r, s;

s = 'This is [[Make]] and the value of [[Make]] is [[[BMW]]] and Availability of this [[[BMW]]] is very [High] in market. another value for the [[Make]] is [[[Audi]]] and availability of [[[Audi]]] is [Moderate]';

// [[[]]] or [[]] or []
r = /\[\[\[(.*?)\]\]\]|\[\[(.*?)\]\]|\[(.*?)\]/g;
s = s.replace(r, function ($0, $1, $2, $3) {
    if ($1) return '(3x[]:' + $1 + ')';
    if ($2) return '(2x[]:' + $2 + ')';
    if ($3) return '(1x[]:' + $3 + ')';
});

document.body.textContent = s;
```